# Hadoop 2.2 namenode running but datanode is not running

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

I am installing hadoop v2.2 first time from this tutorial ( [link](http://thecodeway.blogspot.in/2013/11/hadoop-220-installation-steps-for.html) ).

My namenode is running fine on `http://localhost:50070/` 
But my datanode is not running : `http://localhost:50030/` .

Please tell me if you need the output of any command.

Thanks

Comment: What does your datanode log file say? You should see an error message.

Comment: Logs are : http://pastebin.com/341d8KvW , There are errors but I don't find any solution to them online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for hadoop 2.2.0 installation guide on linux machines

```
http://nextgenhadoop.blogspot.in/2013/10/steps-to-install-hadoop-220-stable.html
```

Comment: Seems to me you are the author. Please tell me have you tried this? If yes, then in which version of UBUNTU?

Comment: I have installed it on ubuntu 12.04 and elementary luna

Comment: Have u tried this ??. seems my blog works for most of the users. verify your installation with your existing installation

Comment: Thanks man. Worked perfectly in ubuntu 12.04. Thankyou so much for your post. was trying to install it from 3 days. Please change your command  "bin/hadoop hdfs -copyFromLocal input /input"  to "bin/hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal input /input"  in your blog post. Rest is perfect. I would recommend to mention about setting java home and other things you have mentioned in prerequisites for new users.

Answer (score 1):

1. first stop all the entities like namenode, datanode etc. (you will
   be having some script or command to do that)
2. Format tmp directory
3. Go to /var/cache/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs/dfs/ and delete all the contents in the directory manually
4. Now format your namenode again
5. start all the entities then use jps command to confirm that the datanode has been started
6. Now run whichever application you may like or have.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your datanode may be running but i think *Web UI* which u written is not correct for it so first try "jps" command in terminal.

if it is not showing datanode then

- stop daemons(by  stop-dfs.sh )
- Clear all content in the folder "mydata/hdfs/datanode"(according to your link)
- run a command "start-dfs.sh"

May this work.

Comment: Can anybody plase tell me proper Web UI for hadoop 2.2.0 ?